# Hard link creation - Permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, hard-link

Which permissions affect hard link creation? Does file ownership itself matter?

---

Suppose user `alice` wants to create a hard link to the file `target.txt` in a directory `target-dir`.

- Which permissions does `alice` need on both `target.txt` and `target-dir`?
- If `target.txt` is owned by user `bill` and `target-dir` is owned by user `chad`, does that change anything?

---

I've tried to simulate this situation by creating the following folder/file structure on an `ext4` filesystem:

```
#> ls -lh . *
.:
drwxr-xr-x 2 bill bill 60 Oct  1 11:29 source-dir
drwxrwxrwx 2 chad chad 60 Oct  1 11:40 target-dir

source-dir:
-r--r--r-- 1 bill bill 0 Oct  1 11:29 target.txt

target-dir:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alice alice 0 Oct  1 11:40 dummy
```

While `alice` can create a soft link to `target.txt`, she can't create a hard link:

```
#> ln source-dir/target.txt target-dir/
ln: failed to create hard link ‘target-dir/target.txt’ => ‘source-dir/target.txt’: Operation not permitted
```

If `alice` owns `target.txt` and no permissions are changed, the hard link succeeds. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this for an assignment?  It may affect the kind of answers some will choose to give if so (not that it would be out of bounds to ask a question about an assignment of course).  Anyway, have you tried just creating that scenario and seeing what happens?

Comment: No it's not for an assignment. I'm facing this exact scenario, and have some guesses, but I thought it would be better to ask from a theoretical standpoint. In my case i'm unable to create the hard-link  regardless of `target.txt` and `target-dir` permissions, unless I `sudo` as root.

Comment: Hard links share the same ownership and permissions, so it's the same as accessing the original file.

Comment: @teppic My difficult is not accessing the created hard-link, it is creating the hard-link as `alice`.I can access both the original file and a hard-link to it (created with `sudo`), but I can't create the link as the user `alice` despite we all agreeing these permissions should be enough for it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To create the hard link, `alice` will need `write+execute` permissions on `target-dir` on all cases. The permissions needed on `target.txt` will vary:

- If `fs.protected_hardlinks = 1` then `alice` needs either ownership of `target.txt` or at least `read+write` permissions on it.
- If `fs.protected_hardlinks = 0` then any set of permissions will do; Even 000 is okay.

---

[This answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209452/134135) had the missing piece of information to answer this question.

From [this commit message](https://lwn.net/Articles/482544/) (emphasis mine):

> On systems that have user-writable directories on the same partition
> as system files, a long-standing class of security issues is the
> hardlink-based time-of-check-time-of-use race, most commonly seen in
> world-writable directories like /tmp. The common method of exploitation
> of this flaw is to cross privilege boundaries when following a given
> hardlink (i.e. a root process follows a hardlink created by another
> user). Additionally, an issue exists where users can "pin" a potentially
> vulnerable setuid/setgid file so that an administrator will not actually
> upgrade a system fully.
>
> **The solution is to permit hardlinks to only be created when the user is
> already the existing file's owner, or if they already have read/write
> access to the existing file**.

Comment: Why would I get "operation not permitted" even when I have rwx perms on the dir and rw perms on the file?

Answer (score 1):

`alice` needs **at least** read permission on `target.txt` and write+execute permission on `target-dir`.

Now, the permission structure works as a threefold separated set:

1. User permissions: apply to the **user** that owns the node.
2. Group permissions: apply to any user **belonging to the group** that owns the node.
3. Others' permissions: apply to **any other user/group** not owning the node.

Therefore, the ownership question affects only in which set of permissions the required permissions for `alice` are, being:

- If `alice` is the owner user, the required permissions must be in the "user" part.
- If `alice` is part of the group that owns it, the required permissions must be in the "group" part.
- If `alice` does not own it and is not part of the group that owns it, the required permissions must be in the "other" part.

Comment: I thought so as well. But in my situation `target.txt` has 444 permissions and `target-dir` has 777 permissions yet I'm unable to create a hard-link unless I do so as root or I own the file I'm linking to. Oddly enough, a _soft_-link will work as you describe.

Comment: That information would be useful to have in the question itself, I recommend you to update.
Oddly enough I didn't think of it before... but does the file system where you are working support Unix-like ownerships/permissions, to start with?

Comment: Yes it does, it is an out-of-the-box ext4 on a fedora 21 system; The link do works when I'm the owner of the file.

Comment: _Oddly enough, a soft-link will work as you describe._

A soft-link is nothing more than a file of a special type with some text. The text is the path pointed to by the link. You can put arbitrary text there: `ln -s 'this is my text' my-soft-link` works just fine. Since it's just a file with a special type, you only need write permission to the directory where you create the soft-link.