# What permissions on a file or directory are needed to cp, mv and rename or make a hard/symbolic link by a different user?

Tags: linux, permissions

I can copy the /etc/passwd file which is owned by `root` to my home directory with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2751 Dec 24 21:26 /etc/passwd
```

I can't do the same with:

```
-rw-------. 1 root root 43591 Dec 27 18:32 /var/log/messages
```

So I am guessing that the read permission for `others` is making the copying possible?

For making a hardlink, I created file1 as root user in my home directory and tried creating a hardlink as a regular user. I wasn't able to.

`-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root       0 Dec 27 18:39 file1`

What is preventing the creation of hardlink?

The directory permissions where file1 resides are:
`drwx------. 18 student student 4096 Dec 27 18:42 .`

I am able to rename the file1 to file2 so I am guessing, same as copy, the read permission on `others` is making that happen?

Lastly, I am not able to move file2 to a different location. Why?

Edit: I have looked at a question that explains permissions about hardlinks but I don't understand what permissions are needed to copy, move and rename files and directories of other users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hard-link creation - Permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233275/hard-link-creation-permissions)

Comment: I am still not sure what permissions are needed to copy, move and rename files and directories owned by others or root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am guessing that the read permission for others is making the copying possible?

Copying a file is just reading the file contents, creating a new file, and writing the data there. You need permission to read the original file, and write permission to the directory of the new file to be able to create it.
See [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373)

> What is preventing the creation of hardlink?

Probably the `fs.protected_hardlinks` sysctl, mentioned in [Hard-link creation - Permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233275/170373). If set, you can only create a hard link if you either own the file or have read and write permission to it, in addition to write access to the directory of the new link. If it's not set, you just need write access to the directory of the new link.

There's a similar knob for symlinks, `fs.protected_hardlinks`. Both are meant to stop various vulnerabilities where a privileged process follows a link that could be modified by an unprivileged process, e.g. in `/tmp`. the knobs are [described in the `proc(5)` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/proc.5.en.html).

Like mentioned in the comments, the symlink/hardlink protections are likely to be enabled by default in most common Linux distributions.

> I am able to rename the file1 to file2 so I am guessing, same as copy, the read permission on others is making that happen?
>
> Lastly, I am not able to move file2 to a different location. Why?

Moving a file within a single filesystem is the same as renaming it. You need write permission to both the old and the new directory, and if moving a *directory*, write permission to the directory itself. ("Moving" a file across filesystems requires making a new file, copying the contents over, and removing the original.) The [man page for the `rename()` system call](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages-dev/rename.2.en.html) describes at least some of the requirements in the descriptions of the EACCES and EPERM errors.

The common theme here is that the data of directories is *filenames*, (or "hard" links), which then point at the inodes describing the actual *file*. The access permissions of a directory control access to that data, so changes to filenames. Hence, creating, deleting, moving and renaming files  requires write permission to the directory or directories containing the affected filenames.

In all cases, you also need the search/access permission (`x` bit) too all directories on the path to the affected files/filenames. (See [`path_resolution(7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/path_resolution.7.en.html))

Comment: Just a comment. `fs.protected_hardlinks`  seems to be set to 1 by default in the Linux flavors that I've checked.

Comment: @doneal24, yep, not surprising for general-use systems where cross-user links are likely not very useful...

Comment: What about removing a directory you own? I am unable to delete a directory that has 400 or 300 permissions in my home directory. I can only remove it if it has 700 permissions.

Comment: @Cruise5, the permissions of the to-be-deleted directory don't matter, as far as I can tell. `mkdir y; chmod 0 y; rmdir y` works fine for me. You just need write access to the containing directory (and `x` access for all directories in the path) and you can't remove a directory you don't own in a sticky (`+t`) directory, but that's not your case there. If it doesn't work for you, post another question with the details.

Answer (score 12):

## Fundamental metaphor: Directories are not Folders

The fundamental concept to understand is the concept of a *directory*. This is important: Unix does *not* have *folders*, it has *directories*.

This distinction is important: a folder *contains* things. A directory *lists* things. If you think of folders, you have the wrong metaphor stuck in your head. Think of the company directory you find in the lobby of an office building: the directory does not *contain* the offices, it *lists* them. Likewise, your phonebook does not *contain* your friends, it *lists* them. On the other hand, a (physical) folder actually *does contain* the (physical) files it holds.

## File Serial Numbers

In Unix, files do not have names. Files only have a *File Serial Number (FSN)*. FSNs are unique within a single filesystem: no two files on the same filesystem have the same FSN and single file only has a single FSN over its lifetime. Note, however, that files on *different* filesystems can have the same FSN.

### inodes

Note: you may encounter the term *inode*. It essentially means the same thing. *File Serial Number* is a name that was invented for the standardization of Unix, because *inodes* are actually an implementation detail of some filesystems and many modern filesystems don't even *have* inodes anymore … but they still need to have FSNs. Also, many modern Unices allow mounting foreign filesystems, which obviously do not have inodes either since that is purely a Unix thing (e.g. mounting a FAT, exFAT, or NTFS filesystem in Linux). The Unix drivers for those foreign filesystems are still required to synthesize FSNs, though, since much of the filesystem APIs are based on FSNs.

## Directories

*Directories* are *special files* that associate *names* to *FSNs*. In very early, very simple Unix filesystems, a directory was quite literally just a file (similar to a text file) that looked something like

```
12345 foo
54321 hello.txt
34343 My 2021 taxes.xlsx
```

Modern filesystems are much more sophisticated, of course, but *conceptually*, that is still how it works today in even the most sophisticated filesystems.

## The three fundamental concepts

If you understand these three concepts, you understand everything you need to know about Unix filesystems and Unix permissions:

- Files don't have names, they only have File Serial Numbers.
- Directories are files.
- Directories associate names with FSNs.

Think about how our telephone system works: we only have numbers, but we have *directories* (phonebooks, Yellow Pages, or in more modern times, a Contact app on our phone) which associate names with those numbers.

## (Hard)links

The association between a *name* and an *FSN* is called a *link* or sometimes a *hardlink* (in contexts where it could be confused with a symlink / softlink).

## Consequences of the three fundamental concepts

Once you internalize those three concepts, everything else should fall into place.

It should now be immediately obvious that there is nothing stopping you from creating multiple name→FSN links for the same FSN in different directories, or even in the same directory. In other words, the same file can have multiple names and exist at multiple paths.

It should also be immediately obvious that this trivially leads to hierarchical directory structures: since directories are just files like any other file, they have FSNs just like any other file, and thus, I can list a directory inside a directory.

It is less obvious but important to understand that the `rm` utility does *not* actually remove a *file*! It removes a *link*, in other words, it removes an entry in a directory. The library function and the kernel system call used by `rm` is actually called `unlink`. In fact, you *cannot* actually remove files in Unix. Files will be automatically removed if there is no link pointing to them (in other words if they have 0 names) and there is no open file handle for the file.

This also explains something that many Windows users get confused about: how is it possible that I can delete a file that is still open in some application? And how does that application not crash? Well, with what we learned in the last paragraph, the answer is simple: they *didn't* delete *the file*, they only deleted the *name*. The file still exists. It could still have other names, but even if this was the last name, the file will not be deleted until the application has closed it. In fact, creating a temporary file, opening it and then immediately "deleting" it again is a common design pattern for Unix applications that need to temporarily store data but don't want to clutter the filesystem with temporary files.

## Applying the concepts to permissions

If you understand that directories are files, and that directories associate names with numbers, then the permissions become clear:

- If you want to *rename*, you need to *write* the new name to the directory and delete (which is also a form of *writing*) the old one, ergo you need `w`rite permission *to the directory*, but *no access whatsoever to the file*. In fact, renaming doesn't actually have anything to do with the file itself at all, it only concerns the *name* which is *not* a property of the file itself.
- If you want to list a directory, you need to *read* its contents and therefore need `r`read permissions on the directory.
- Creating a hardlink is just *writing* to the directory, ergo you need `w`rite permissions to the directory. And so on.

## Concrete examples

With our three core concepts in mind, we should be able to answer all of your questions:

### copy

> I can copy the `/etc/passwd` file which is owned by `root` to my home directory with the following permissions:
>
> ```
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2751 Dec 24 21:26 /etc/passwd
> ```
>
> I can't do the same with:
>
> ```
> -rw-------. 1 root root 43591 Dec 27 18:32 /var/log/messages
> ```
>
> So I am guessing that the read permission for `others` is making the copying possible?

That is correct. Just think about what does "copy a file" actually *mean*: you are *creating* a *new* file (which automatically also means you need to give it a name, i.e. create a *link* entry in the target directory) which has the *same content* as the original file.

In order to do that, you need two permissions:

- You need `w`rite permission on the target directory in order to create the hardlink to the newly created file.
- You need `r`ead permission on the original file in order to read its content because if you can't read its content then how can you recreate it?

### link

> For making a hardlink, I created `file1` as root user in my home directory and tried creating a hardlink as a regular user. I wasn't able to.
>
> ```
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root    root       0 Dec 27 18:39 file1
> ```

There is nothing in the standard Unix permission model preventing you from creating the hardlink. All you need is `w`rite permission to the directory. The permissions for the file are irrelevant since you don't need to touch it.

I just tested it on my OS (macOS 12.1 "Monterey") on an APFS filesystem, and it works just fine.

#### fs.protected_hardlinks

> What is preventing the creation of hardlink?

Nothing in the Unix permission system does. However, since you are using Linux, there is a Linux-specific configuration option, which may prevent you from doing so: the `fs.protected_hardlinks` sysctl.

Quoting from [the official sysctl documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.rst#n219) [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## protected_hardlinks
>
> […]
>
> When set to "`0`", hardlink creation behavior is unrestricted.
>
> When set to "`1`" **hardlinks cannot be created by users if they do not already own the source file, or do not have read/write access to it**.

It looks like you have configured it to `1` (restricted). Check `/proc/sys/fs/protected_hardlinks` to be sure.

### rename

> The directory permissions where file1 resides are:
>
> ```
>  drwx------. 18 student student 4096 Dec 27 18:42 .
> ```
>
> I am able to rename the `file1` to `file2` so I am guessing, same as copy, the read permission on `others` is making that happen?

For a *rename*, you only need `w`rite permission on the directory, which you have. You never touch the content of the file, therefore, its permissions are irrelevant.

### move

> Lastly, I am not able to move `file2` to a different location. Why?

That depends on what, *exactly*, you mean by "move", and what, *exactly*, you mean by "different location", and what, *exactly* you mean by "not able to".

There are two ways how you could interpret "move":

1. Delete the original and recreate the same content under a different name.
2. Delete the link in the source directory and create a link in the target directory.

If you use the `mv` utility, it actually could do either of those, so let's look at both of them.

#2 is just a rename: you need `w`rite permission to the source directory so that you can delete the link and you need `w`rite permission to the target directory so that you can create the link. At no point do you need to touch the file, or access its contents, so the permissions are irrelevant. In fact, `mv` will use the `rename` syscall for this.

`mv` will try to do #2 whenever possible.

So, when is #2 *not* possible? Well, remember that FSNs are only unique *within one filesystem*. Also, *files* only exist *within a filesystem*.

So, it should be clear that #2 is only possible if the source directory and the target directory are *on the same filesystem*. If they are on different filesystems, `mv` will instead *copy* the file to the target and then unlink the original. Which means, as we discussed above, in addition to `w`rite access to the source directory and `w`rite access to the target directory, it also needs `r`ead access to the original file.

## Execute permissions

Note: so far, we have only looked at the `r`ead and `w`rite permissions, but we have completely ignored the e`x`ecute permission.

### … for regular files

For regular files, the e`x`ecute permission is fairly obvious: it gives permission to execute the file. (No, really?) However, note that "execute" has a specific meaning here: it means "passing it to the kernel to execute".

In particular, you do *not* need e`x`ecute permission to pass a file to a script interpreter. So, if you have a script file called `myscript` in a fictional language called MyLanguage that looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env mylanguage

print "Hello, World!"
```

Then you *do* need e`x`ecute permission if you execute it like this:

```sh
/path/to/myscript
```

but you do *not* need e`x`ecute permission if you execute it like this:

```sh
mylanguage /path/to/myscript
```

The language interpreter only needs `r`read permission so that it can read the content of the script file.

Or, to be more precise, *the system* does not require you to have e`x`ecute permission, but the `mylanguage` interpreter, *could*, if it wanted to, check if you have e`x`ecute permission. And in fact, some interpreters do that, and some don't.

### … for directories

What does e`x`ecute permission mean for directories? What is being executed here?

For directories, e`x`ecute permission is interpreted as "enter" permission or "lookup" permission. In other words, the e`x`ecute permission allows you to ask the directory for an FSN, given a name.

You can think of the directory as a very simple program which takes a *name* as a parameter and returns an *FSN*, then the idea of "e`x`ecute permission" kind of makes sense. But it is a really strenuous idea. Just ignore the fact that the `x` stands for e`x`ecute and think of `x` meaning "lookup" or "enter" for directories.

## Other kinds of special files

Directories are not the only kind of special files there are. There are five others:

- *symbolic links*,
- *pipes*,
- *sockets*,
- *character special files*, and
- *block special files*.

### Symlinks

Of these five, the ones you encounter most often are *symbolic links* or *symlinks*.

A symlink is essentially a file that contains a *path*. In very early, very simple Unix filesystems, symlinks where quite literally just text files that contained a path. And that's more or less still how you can think of them today.

Once you understand this, it should be clear that in order to create a symlink to somewhere, all you need to be able to do is create the file. You do not need access to the path that you put into the file. In fact, that path does not even have to exist!

For example, assuming you are allowed to create files at all, you can easily do

```sh
ln -s https://www.google.com/ google
```

This is a perfectly valid symlink: `google` is a perfectly valid name and `https://www.google.com/` is a perfectly valid path (it means "the directory named `www.google.com` inside the directory named `https:` inside the current directory), but of course it is not pointing to an actually existing file, although you *could* do

```sh
mkdir -p https:/www.google.com
```

to make it point to somewhere if you wanted to:

```sh
cd google
# no error
```

Comment: Great answer! What literature would you recommend to learn more about Unix in this way?

Comment: So, for a move, if I have write permissions to both directories, but `0` for the file itself, I'll still be able to move the file?

Answer (score 0):

Hard links are linking to the storage of the file and will have the same inode. So you cannot hard link unless the "others" has write permissions.

If the file was 646 perms, you would then be able to hard link to the file. Finally, type ls -i filename of your hard link and original file. You will see that they have the same inode.

Comment: I'm not sure that this sounds quite right. The target directory needs write and execute permissions and the source file may (or may not) need only read permissions. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260191/97255) to [Hard-link creation - Permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233275/97255)

Comment: I actually tested it to verify before I commented. You cant hardlink if not owner with others having write perms.

Comment: OK, good. If you could [edit] your answer and add the information in the comment, that would be great, as comments section is not where additional information should be put (that isn't what it is for). Also, maybe expand upon it with some examples (for example, showing the output of `ls -l`), to clarify your answer. As it stands, your answer isn't particularly clear.