# root cannot connect to symlinked socket of other user

Tags: ssh, symlink, su, socket

I use oh-my-zsh's ssh-agent plugin to have a static symlink to my current `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` created. When connecting through SSH with agent forwarding enabled the  file `/tmp/ssh-agent-$USER-screen` is symlinked to `/tmp/ssh-<whatever>/agent.<some numbers>`:

```
agross@router ~
$ ls -la /tmp/ssh-agent*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 agross agross 30 Jan  7 21:35 /tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen -> /tmp/ssh-uoof1WiDSw/agent.7745

agross@router ~
$ ls -la /tmp/ssh-uoof1WiDSw/
srwxr-xr-x. 1 agross agross  0 Jan  7 21:35 agent.7745
```

I tested the symlink successfully with `ssh-add -l`:

```
agross@router ~
$ ssh-add -l
2048 15:5a:dd... /home/agross/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

agross@router ~
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen
```

As soon as I `su` I cannot access the symlink anymore, but the symlink target works fine.

```
[root@router ~]# socat -v - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen
2016/01/07 21:51:04 socat[16054] E connect(3, AF=1 "/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen", 30): Permission denied

[root@router ~]# socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-uoof1WiDSw/agent.7745
<empty line is printed so I guess I'm connected>

[root@router ~]# echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen

[root@router ~]# ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

[root@router ~]# SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-uoof1WiDSw/agent.7745 ssh-add -l
2048 15:5a:dd... /home/agross/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

I researched that the permissions on the symlink are not evaluated, rather the permissions on the symlink target are relevant to decide weather a user (root even?) is able to access a file. And accessing the symlink target works flawlessly.

What could be the problem here?

I'm running CentOS 7, in case it matters. Thank you!

---

#### Updated afters questions:

#### `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is exported

I don't think it matters w.r.t. not being able to connect to the symlink with `socat`, though.

```
[root@router ~]# export | grep SSH
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen"
```

#### SELinux

Seems like that doesn't matter as well.

```
[root@router ~]# getenforce
Enforcing
[root@router ~]# setenforce 0
[root@router ~]# socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen
2016/01/08 09:54:09 socat[21673] E connect(3, AF=1 "/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen", 30): Permission denied
[root@router ~]# setenforce 1
[root@router ~]# socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen
2016/01/08 09:54:45 socat[21675] E connect(3, AF=1 "/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen", 30): Permission denied
```

#### Symlink in ~ vs symlink in /tmp

Thanks to @masm for the pointer. A symlink in my home directory works, whereas the symlink in /tmp doesn't.

```
[root@router ~]# ls -lZ /home/agross
lrwxrwxrwx. agross agross unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 foo -> /tmp/ssh-QlnhyjUQDp/agent.15895

[root@router ~]# socat -v - UNIX-CONNECT:/home/agross/foo
<empty line>

[root@router ~]# ls -lZ /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx. agross agross unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 ssh-agent-agross-screen -> /tmp/ssh-QlnhyjUQDp/agent.15895

[root@router ~]# socat -v - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen
2016/01/08 18:14:48 socat[15989] E connect(3, AF=1 "/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen", 30): Permission denied
```

Comment: Is the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable `export`ed into environment of the `ssh-add` you are spawning from the shell?

Comment: CentOS is using SELinux. Even if you are root, applications might be confined. Can you check the same use case with SELinux in permissive mode (`setenforce 0`)?

Comment: @peterph Thanks for your question! Yes, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is exported.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks for your question! SELinux doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: I reproduced the error with only socat (without ssh). If you can use otherwhere (e.g. your home) instead of /tmp, it may work. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.protected_symlinks=1` was the culprit:

```
[root@router ~]# sysctl fs.protected_symlinks
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
[root@router ~]# sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0
fs.protected_symlinks = 0

[root@router ~]# socat -v - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen

[root@router ~]# sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1

[root@router ~]# socat -v - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen
2016/01/09 01:46:21 socat[20591] E connect(3, AF=1 "/tmp/ssh-agent-agross-screen", 30): Permission denied
```

Kudos: https://askubuntu.com/questions/599719/how-can-i-set-a-symlink-from-tmp-mysql-sock

Comment: [Reported to oh-my-zsh.](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4763)