# Symbolic link not working as expected when changes user

Tags: permissions, root, symlink, chown, tmp

Symbolic link not working, using standard UBUNTU 16 LTS... It shows "Permission denied" where I expected to get access, not working even after `chown`.

Full example:

```sh
sudo rm /tmp/file.txt  # if exist, remove

cd ~
sudo chmod 666 data/file.txt
ls -l data/file.txt    # "-rw-rw-rw-" as expected
more data/file.txt     # working fine
sudo ln -sf $PWD/data/file.txt /tmp/file.txt  # fine
ls -l /tmp/file.txt    # "lrwxrwxrwx",  /tmp/file.txt -> /home/thisUser/file.txt
more /tmp/file.txt     # fine

sudo chown -h postgres:postgres /tmp/file.txt

sudo more /tmp/file.txt   #  NOT WORK! but its is sudo! and 666!
```

Comment: What does "NOT WORK" mean?

Comment: I guess what you want is: `sudo chown postgres:postgres /tmp/file.txt`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These actions should result with an error message: **Permission denied**. The directory, `/tmp`, has permissions including the sticky bit. The error is a result of the kernel configuration for `fs.protected_symlinks`.

To show the setting, `sysctl fs.protected_symlinks`. This equals `1` when set. To disable temporarily, which is *not recommended*, `sysctl fs.protected_symlinks=0`. To turn off permanently, which is again *not recommended*, `sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0`.

See [patchwork.kernel.org](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1147961/) for more information.

To avoid link rot, the leading summary paragraphs on symbolic links from the hyperlink follow.

> Kees Cook - July 2, 2012, 8:17 p.m.

> This adds symlink and hardlink restrictions to the Linux VFS.

> Symlinks:

> A long-standing class of security issues is the symlink-based
> time-of-check-time-of-use race, most commonly seen in world-writable
> directories like /tmp. The common method of exploitation of this flaw
> is to cross privilege boundaries when following a given symlink (i.e. a
> root process follows a symlink belonging to another user). For a likely
> incomplete list of hundreds of examples across the years, please see:
> http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=/tmp

> The solution is to permit symlinks to only be followed when outside
> a sticky world-writable directory, or when the uid of the symlink and
> follower match, or when the directory owner matches the symlink's owner.

Comment: hum.. yes `sudo sysctl fs.protected_symlinks` is `1`... I try `sudo sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0` and ... Perfect! `more /tmp/file.txt` works!  Ok... As it is danger, rapidly `sudo sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=1` (and permission denied back as expected)... Well, no other workaround?  I can't  do a `cp` for a file that changes all time....