# PTY accessible by group membership inaccessible by symlink?

Tags: linux, permissions, symlink

I'm setting up a Linux application which interfaces with programs designed to talk to a serial port. What's strange is that while I can access the pty by symlink if I am the owner user (`klipper`), I can't if I'm not, even if the other user (`octoprint`) is in the pty's owning group.

For context, the symlink is at `/tmp/printer` and the pty is at `/dev/pts/1`. SELinux is not installed and mount options are `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)`

```
$ ls -l /tmp/printer
lrwxrwxrwx 1 klipper klipper 10 Oct 19 21:30 /tmp/printer -> /dev/pts/1

$ ls -l /dev/pts/1
crw-rw---- 1 klipper tty 136, 1 Oct 19 22:41 /dev/pts/1

$ groups klipper
network tty uucp klipper

$ sudo -u octoprint picocom /tmp/printer
<...>
FATAL: cannot open /tmp/printer: Permission denied

$ sudo -u octoprint picocom /dev/pts/1
<...>
Terminal ready
```

Comment: For a more general question, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336625/ .

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the sticky bit typically set on`/tmp`. If you look at the permissions on `/tmp`, you’ll see that the last bit is `t` which implies that accessing a symlink inside of `/tmp` is limited to the owner of it. Your solution could be creating the symlink at another location.