# Group permissions for root not working in /tmp

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, mount, manjaro, tmpfs

I experienced a strange behaviour in my /tmp directory. Although a user belongs to a group that has permissions to read/write a file, he cannot do so.

In this example, I create a new file `/tmp/test.txt` as user `max`. I give it the 777 permissions and make the file belong to the group `root`, but user `root` still cannot edit it.

```
su max
touch /tmp/test.txt
chmod 777 /tmp/test.txt

su root
chown max:root /tmp/test.txt

# ls -l /tmp/test.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max root 0 26. Feb 12:08 test.txt

# echo "foobar" > /tmp/test.txt
bash: /tmp/test.txt: Permission denied
```

When moving `test.txt` to a different directory, everything works as expected.

`/tmp` is a tmpfs mounted via fstab via the following options:

```
tmpfs       /tmp    tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=5G    0 0
```

When running `ls -l /`, the tmp folder looks like the following:

```
drwxrwxrwt  20 root root   640 26. Feb 12:01 tmp/
```

I am running Manjaro, an Arch Linux derivate.

Did I do something wrong with mounting tmpfs?

Comment: What user is doing the `echo` with the redirect.  The prompt is that of a non-root user.

Comment: We're heading either for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148592/ or for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336625/ + https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209309/ I suspect.  (-:

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry for the ambiguity. The command is run as root (not with sudo, I know about issues with it). Fixed in the answer

Comment: @JdeBP Are you sure one of those applies? I neither run the echo with sudo, nor do I work with soft/hardlinks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The behavior you are showing seems to depend on the `fs.protected_regular` Linux kernel parameter, introduced along with `fs.protected_fifos` by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5) (converged in version 4.19, I believe), with the aim to fix security vulnerabilities.

Excerpt of the commit message (emphasis mine):

> namei: allow restricted O_CREAT of FIFOs and regular files
>
> Disallows open of FIFOs or **regular files not owned by the user in world writable sticky directories, unless the owner is the same as that of the directory or the file is opened without the O_CREAT flag**. The purpose is to make data spoofing attacks harder. ...

The same commit message also reports a list of related Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE) numbers.

Thus, provided that `userX` is `root` or is otherwise granted write access to `/tmp/file`, and that `/tmp` is a world writable directory with the sticky bit set, they can open `file` for writing only if:

- `userX` is the owner of `file`; or
- both `file` and directory `/tmp` are owned by the same user.

In your test, `root` has write permissions on `/tmp/test.txt`, but is not the owner of the file, nor have `/tmp/test.txt` and `/tmp` the same owner (respectively `max` and `root`).

The issue appears to be totally unrelated to the way `/tmp` is mounted.

The relevant documentation is in [Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5):

> protected_fifos:
>
> The intent of this protection is to avoid unintentional writes to an attacker-controlled FIFO, where a program expected to create a regular file.
>
> ...
>
> protected_regular:
>
> This protection is similar to protected_fifos, but it avoids writes to an attacker-controlled regular file, where a program expected to create one.
>
> When set to "0", writing to regular files is unrestricted.
>
> When set to "1" don't allow O_CREAT open on regular files that we don't own in world writable sticky directories, unless they are owned by the owner of the directory.
>
> When set to "2" it also applies to group writable sticky directories.

That is, the protection described above can be disabled with the command:

```
sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
```

A bit of testing to backup our hypothesis:

```
$ su - root
# sysctl fs.protected_regular
fs.protected_regular = 1
# cd /
# mkdir test
# chmod 1777 test
# su - otheruser
$ echo hello >/test/somefile
$ exit
logout
# cat /test/somefile
hello
# ls -lah test/somefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 otheruser otheruser 6 Feb 26 17:21 test/somefile
# echo root >>test/somefile
-bash: test/somefile: Permission denied
# sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
fs.protected_regular = 0
# echo root >>test/somefile
# cat /test/somefile
hello
root
# sysctl fs.protected_regular=1
fs.protected_regular = 1
# echo root >>test/somefile
-bash: test/somefile: Permission denied
# chmod 0777 /test/
# echo root >>test/somefile
# cat test/somefile 
hello
root
root
```

Unlike `fs.protected_hardlinks` and `fs.protected_symlinks`, `fs.protected_regular` and `fs.protected_fifos` are not enabled by default in the kernel code.
Enabling them is a backward incompatible change (as the example you provided in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp/503169?noredirect=1#comment928326_503169) points out) and, as far as I can tell, `systemd` did it in version 241, with [this recent commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/2732587540035227fe59e4b64b60127352611b35).

Credits: thanks to [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) for pointing in the right direction with a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp#comment927896_503111) to the question.

Comment: It works, thank you very much! It also affects Docker containers running on a system with `fs.protected_regular=1`. This for example causes an error when running openproject/community:8

Comment: What happened to Linus' plea "Don't break user space!".?

Comment: user space isn't broken here, if user space sets a flag that later breaks user space than that's the user space's fault not Linux's