# Permission denied when writing to '/tmp/file' as root

Tags: permissions

This simple script

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/a
echo a > /tmp/a
chmod a+w /tmp/a
echo b >> /tmp/a
sudo bash -c 'whoami; echo c >> /tmp/a'
```

outputs

```
root
bash: /tmp/a: Permission denied
```

Why does root not have permissions to write to `/tmp/a`?

Here's a reproducible way to demonstrate this via Docker:

```
# alpine 3.8
alpine=$(docker run -d alpine:3.8 sleep 99999999999999)
d() { docker exec $alpine "$@"; }
d apk add sudo bash
d adduser -D u
d sudo -u u bash -c 'echo a > /tmp/a; chmod a+w /tmp/a'
d bash -c 'whoami; echo b >> /tmp/a'
docker rm -f $alpine

# ubuntu 18.04
ubuntu=$(docker run -d ubuntu:18.04 sleep 99999999999999)
d() { docker exec $ubuntu "$@"; }
d useradd u
d apt-get update
d apt-get install -y sudo
d sudo -u u bash -c 'echo a > /tmp/a; chmod a+w /tmp/a'
d bash -c 'whoami; echo b >> /tmp/a'
docker rm -f $ubuntu
```

Comment: When I try this on my system (Ubuntu 18.04) it works perfectly and there is no permission denied error.

Comment: I've added an Ubuntu 18.04 example which also fails.

Comment: maybe it is something Docker-specific? I am not using Docker

Comment: No, I'm getting this error on regular systems, Docker is just for reproducibility.

Comment: ok well good luck, I am using a regular system and not seeing it.

Comment: In your system what is the output of `sudo sysctl fs.protected_symlinks`?

Comment: It's `1`. The error indeed disappears when using a path that is not `/tmp/`-prefixed. But why is this relevant when there are no symlinks involved?

Comment: See [Group permissions for root not working in /tmp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp).

Comment: That solves it, thanks! Do you want to add an answer that I can accept? Or should a mod mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group permissions for root not working in /tmp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp)

Comment: My suggestion is to mark it as a duplicate. :) You're welcome.