# How can I read from named pipe line by line and exit?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, read, fifo

I have the following bash script that I'd like to use as a fuzzy file opener. I create a fifo, spawn a new terminal with fzf running and redirect fzf's output to the fifo. I then call a function that reads from the fifo and opens the files.

My problem is that the while loop inside the `open` function never ends. How can I close the fifo once all the lines have been read?

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FIFO=/tmp/fuzzy-opener
[ -e "$FIFO" ] || mkfifo "$FIFO"
exec 3<> "$FIFO"

function open {
  while read file; do
    # open every $file based on its mime-type
  done <&3
  echo 'done' # this is never reached
}

alacritty -e sh -c "fzf -m >&3" \
  && open
```

Comment: I don't know `fzf` and the format of its output. [Make sure sole `read` is what you want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a couple of alternatives, because:

- based on the script in your question, a FIFO seems actually not needed;
- in principle, since you are using Bash, you could take advantage of the NUL character as a delimiter (the only byte that is not allowed in a POSIX file path); unfortunately, though, `fzf` does not seem to work with file names containing newline characters;
- reading from a file in `/tmp` may pose a major security issue: if someone else created `/tmp/fuzzy-opener` (as a regular file), your script would happily apply `open` to its content (though, on some systems, opening a not-owned file in a word-writable sticky directory using `exec 3<>` will [raise an error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503111/315749)).

You may use:

```bsh
function open {
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file
  do
    echo "$file"    # Replace with the actual open action
  done
}

alacritty -e sh -c 'fzf -m --disabled --print0 >&3' 3>&1 | open
```

which can be made portable by removing `-d ''` and `--print0` (losing nothing, given the aforementioned limitation of `fzf`); or, using an array to store the selected file names:

```bsh
function open {
  for file
  do
    echo "$file"    # Replace with the actual open action
  done
}

mapfile -t -d '' toopen < <(alacritty -e sh -c 'fzf -m --print0 >&3' 3>&1) &&
  open "${toopen[@]}"
```

In both cases, the main point is that `fzf`'s output is redirected to a new file descriptor obtained duplicating the writing end of a pipe and thus connected to a reader command.

Answer (score 3):

The pipe will show an EOF (return from `read()` with zero bytes read), if the writing side is closed. But I think what happens is that since `<>` opens the pipe in read-write mode, the pipe always has a writer, the shell holding the file handle open.

I think you should be able to skip opening the pipe in the shell, and just do this instead:

```
alacritty -e sh -c "fzf -m >$FIFO" && open < "$FIFO"
```

Or more properly:

```
alacritty -e sh -c 'fzf -m >"$1"' sh "$FIFO" && open < "$FIFO"
```

I'm assuming here that the construct in the question works otherwise, which it should if alacritty spawns a terminal in the background and exits immediately. If it doesn't, you'd need something like `alacritty -e sh ... & open < "$FIFO"` to run both parts at the same time.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, or `alacritty ... & open < ` to run alacritty in the background. But since it seemed to work for them in the question, I suppose alacritty just spawns a window to run the shell through a background process and returns immediately.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, well, the question already had the `&&` there, and the only problem they mention there is that the loop never ends. So yes, I expect it works for them like that. Also yes, it won't work if the first command doesn't exit immediately, in that case, you'd need something else.

Comment: The construct in the question works *regardless* if `alacritty` returns immediately, because there is `<>` and `fzf` doesn't block (unless maybe it fills the fifo buffer). You fixed the original problem by removing `<>` but this may cause `fzf` to block, depending on whether `alacritty` returns early or not. So it's not a case the OP does not mention a problem that might be there. It's a case where your (reasonable) fix may induce a problem that wasn't there. +1 nonetheless. The current revision is useful even if `alacritty` waits for `sh`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, ah, hmm... You have a point. Seems to me it depends on how those two work, exactly. And at least I now need to test it to reason about it any further...

Comment: I was nitpicking because your answer appeared when I was testing and composing mine. That's why I was familiar with some potential problems. Still I decided not to publish a separate answer, because I strongly believe improving a decent answer is better than posting virtually the same answer with minor improvement added. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @ilkkachu If I remove the `exec 3<> "$FIFO"` line, fzf blocks waiting for a reader (same behaviour as `echo foo > $FIFO`). I fixed that by backgrounding alacritty like you suggested, but when does that process exit?