# All attempts at modifying a file leads to 'Permission denied'

Tags: command-line, permissions

I was trying to increase my mouse scroll speed by following https://github.com/tkkcc/libinput_patch which requires modifying a file. Should be easy...

```
$ echo 6 > /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier
bash: /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier: Permission denied
```

Nothing a sudo wont solve right?

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo "6" > /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier'
bash: line 1: /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier: Permission denied
```

Checks permisions

```
$ stat  /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)
```

At this moment I'm at the limit of my abilities. How can I change this file and why it doesn't let me change it even with root privileges? I tried many approaches and search engines are no good on this one.

Edit:
Tried

```
$ echo 6 | sudo tee /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier
tee: /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier: Permission denied
```

```
$ dmesg | tail
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

Comment: tee: /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier: Permission denied.
sadly I tried with tee already

Comment: Can you post your exact command with `tee`? The answers in the link posted by @AndyDalton work for me, even after changing the permissions to 0600 and owned by root.

Comment: Is there anything in the kernel messages? `dmesg | tail`

Comment: @AndyDalton, note that what they're doing there with `sudo` is to have the sudo'ed Bash do the redirection, essentially the as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1418/170373) in that same question.

Comment: If it's Linux, check `lsattr /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier`. Also `mount` or `findmnt` to check what file system `/tmp` is (or `/` if `/tmp` is part of it)

Comment: `sudo dmesg` might help

Comment: This is strange ```lsattr /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier``` lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier

Comment: @ilkkachu Yep, you're right; I didn't notice that.

Comment: Seems this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503111/315749. To make sure, and to also make this Q more likely to help other users, could you please add the output of `ls -l /tmp/libinput_discrete_deltay_multiplier` (to see the file's owner and group) to it? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: ...and the output of `ls -l /tmp` would be useful too, to make sure it is a sticky directory everyone can write to. A way to write to that file should then be to impersonate the file owner: `sudo -u file_owner sh -c 'echo 6 > /tmp/...'`

Comment: I think that would be `ls -ld /tmp`, @fra-san

Comment: @roaima Yes, definitely. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the answer - I have rolled back that edit so that the question conforms with site guidelines. The link to the duplicate is meant to guide visitors to the solution.