Why can't root edit /var/spool/cron/crontabs?
[Please, I don't want to know why I shouldn't edit it; I want to know why I can't edit it]
# pwd
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
# ll sysadmin
-rw------- 1 sysadmin crontab 210 Jun 17 16:05 sysadmin
# getcap sysadmin
# lsattr sysadmin
--------------e------- sysadmin
# filecap /var/spool/cron/crontabs/sysadmin
Unable to get capabilities of /var/spool/cron/crontabs/sysadmin: No data available

This is Ubuntu 22.04, ext4, LVM. I can delete the file, but I can't write to it.
EDIT
crontab -e successfully changes the file, as expected. However, editing the file with a text editor (in my case, emacs, while running as root) simply gives an error message ("Opening output file: Permission denied, /var/spool/cron/crontabs/sysadmin").
EDIT 2
This question isn't about emacs, or any other editor - it appears that crontab -e has some magic which I can't duplicate as a root user, and that the magic is unrelated to file capabilities. If I try echoing to the file as suggested in a comment:
root@vserver:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# echo "foo" >> sysadmin
bash: sysadmin: Permission denied

So what is it that's denying me permission?

You mean you can't edit it with crontab -u sysadmin -e as root?

@Kusalananda: I can't edit it with emacs - I assume that crontab -e would work.

Please [edit] your question and show us i) how you try to edit it and ii) how it fails. Is there an error? What error? Is there no error but your changes disappear? What happens?

You can (and should) use crontab -e regardless of which editor you want to use - just specify emacs via the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variable. See for example crontab -e doesnt shows option to select editor - what to do?

You should include (server-start) in your ~/.emacs, and export EDITOR="$(type -p emacsclient)";export VISUAL="$(type -p emacsclient)";alias emacs="$(type -p emacsclient)"to your shell startup file. Start 1/usr/bin/emacsat login. OnceEDITORandVISUALare set, you can usesudoedit to edit a file (sudoedit, running as root, copies the target file to a temporary location (changing ownership to $USER), then, running as $USER, invokes $EDITORor$VISUALon the temporary copy. If the copy is changed,sudoedit, running as root` copies it back.

Can you edit it with vi or nano, or do things like echo '# hello' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/sysadmin?

@steeldriver: I know that I can edit it with crontab -e - what I'm trying to find out is what magic crontab is using to allow the file to be written to, when a root user can do nothing apart from deleting the file? I'm assuming that there's a kernel config of some sort that's stopping me doing this, hence the sysctl  tag.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: # echo "foo" >> sysadmin reports bash: sysadmin: Permission denied. Root can't write the file; it can only delete the file. This smells like a kernel config of some sort, like a write to a file in /tmp, but I can't find any docs on it.

What does ls -ld /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ say? What is the fs.protected_regular sysctl set to?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: cat /proc/sys/fs/protected_regular gives 2, and ls -ld gives drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab.

Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691441/root-cannot-write-to-file-that-is-owned-by-regular-user

You should be able to edit the file directly ("magic") by running your editor as the user and group owning the file, e.g. sudo -u sysadmin -g crontab vi /var/spool/cron/crontabs/sysadmin  or echo "# foo" | sudo -u sysadmin -g crontab tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/sysadmin

@user4556274: on the dupe - yes, I saw that, thanks, and the fs.protected_regular sysctl does let me edit the file, as more-or-less suggested in the comments above. Your suggestion of editing as the user and group also works (why?). However, I'm still trying to get my head around why fs.protected_regular is relevant, since root owns the directory and the file, and the kernel.org docs explicitly state unless they are owned by the owner of the directory.

Ah - ok - it all makes sense now :) If someone wants to write up an fs.protected_regular answer I'll accept it.
